# Cross-validate precision, recall and f1 together with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

is there any simple way to cross-validate a classifier and calculate precision and recall at once? Currently I use the function

```
cross_validation.cross_val_score(classifier, designMatrix, classes, cv=5, scoring="precision")
```

however it calculates only one metric, so I have to call it 2 times to calculate precision and recall. With a large ML model, the calculation then unnecessarily takes 2 times longer. Is there any built-in better option, or do I have to implement the cross-validation on my own? thanks.

Comment: This is also discussed on [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1837). Appearantly there is a [merge](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7388) coming up focusing on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of the current state of affairs (this feature has been discussed), but you can always get away with the following - awful - hack

```
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, precision_score
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer
recall_accumulator = []
def score_func(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
    recall_accumulator.append(recall_score(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs))
    return precision_score(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs)
scorer = make_scorer(score_func)
```

Then use `scoring=scorer` in your cross-validation. You should find the recall values in the `recall_accumulator` array. Watch out though, this array is global, so make sure you don't write to it in a way you can't interpret the results.

Answer (score 1):

*eickenberg's* answer works when the argument *n_job* of *`cross_val_score()`* is set to 1. To support parallel computing (*n_jobs* > 1), one have to use a shared list instead of a global list. This can be done with the help of *Manager* class from *multiprocessing* module.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer
from multiprocessing import Manager

recall_accumulator = Manager().list()
def score_func(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
    recall_accumulator.append(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred))
    return 0
scorer = make_scorer(score_func)
```

Then the result of each fold will be stored in *`recall_accumulator`*.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched with the same question, so I'm leaving it for the next person.

You can use [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html).
It can have multiple metric names in the `scoring` parameter.

```
scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring=('precision','recall','f1'), cv=5)
```